# SQL Server 2012 not reinstalling

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2012

I have uninstalled everything from control panel with sql server 2012

It can never get past the first window of installation which has product key, license terms, product updates, install Setup files. after it has has installed Setup files the next window does not appear.

my summary file looks like this:

```
<!-- language: none -->
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Passed
  Exit code (Decimal):           0
  Start time:                    2018-03-07 17:22:30
  End time:                      2018-03-07 17:22:52
  Requested action:              RunRules

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  DESKTOP-US6DHAO
  Machine processor count:       4
  OS version:                    Future Windows Version
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
  SQL Server 2012      SQLEXPRESS           MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS             Database Engine Services                 1033                 Express Edition      11.0.2100.60    No        
  SQL Server 2012      SQLEXPRESS           MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS             SQL Server Replication                   1033                 Express Edition      11.0.2100.60    No        
  SQL Server 2012      SQLEXPRESS           MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS             Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search 1033                 Express Edition      11.0.2100.60    No        
  SQL Server 2012      SQLEXPRESS           MSRS11.SQLEXPRESS              Reporting Services - Native              1033                 Express Edition      11.0.2100.60    No        
  SQL Server 2012                                                          Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Express Edition      11.0.2100.60    No        
  SQL Server 2012                                                          Management Tools - Complete              1033                 Express Edition      11.0.2100.60    No        
  SQL Server 2012                                                          Client Tools Connectivity                1033                 Express Edition      11.0.2100.60    No        
  SQL Server 2012                                                          Client Tools Backwards Compatibility     1033                 Express Edition      11.0.2100.60    No        
  SQL Server 2012                                                          Client Tools SDK                         1033                 Express Edition      11.0.2100.60    No        

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2012
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       11
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         C:\Users\RedRam\Downloads\SQLFULL_x64_ENU\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Evaluation

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        RunRules
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  ENU:                           true
  FEATURES:                      
  HELP:                          false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTANCENAME:                  <empty>
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  RULES:                         SCCCheckRules
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180307_172224\ConfigurationFile.ini

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

There are no scenario-specific rules.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20180307_172224\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Any Hints thank you

Comment: You say you uninstalled everything via control panel.  Then you say you cannot install.  Are you trying to install a different version of SQL?  A new copy of an evaluation software or???

Comment: yes the evaluation software

Comment: Are you trying to reinstall  an evaluation version after trial expired?  If so, it will likely fail.  There will be a hidden registry key or something that is checked by the installer

Comment: no I was getting an error, made a big mistake uninstalling, I believe I have uninstalled wrongly i ended up delete the microsoft sql server files deriectly in some cases

Comment: I also uninstalled using control panel and ccleaner to clear regiesters

Comment: I realise now that I installed Express, when i should of installed Evaulation

Comment: I believe when I install the software it still remembers that I have installed Express, So I dont think I have Cleared everything